# Power BI REST API request error 403 when querying the dataset

Tags: access-token, http-status-code-403, azure-service-principal, powerbi-rest-api

I want to query the Power BI dataset using Power BI REST API, app to app authentication (Service Principal).
**I am getting Error 403 (access forbidden) when sending request to Power BI dataset**.

I have:

1. Azure AD App registered
2. SP with **Dataset.Read.All **delegated permission
3. SP added to AAD security group
4. the security group is allowed to use Power BI API (setting under Tenant enabled)
5. the security group has Admin role in Power BI Service workspace.
   I am able to generate the access Token successfully.
   but then **I am getting Error 403 (access forbidden) when sending request to Power BI dataset** using GET or POST method, for example:

GET [https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/{{group_id}}/datasets](https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/%7B%7Bgroup_id%7D%7D/datasets)
Authorization: Bearer Token

Can anyone help on that, what is missing here, thank you.

Comment: Could you include what flow you are using to get bearer token?

Comment: @Sridevi 
I am using client_credentials flow

Comment: When I tried the same in my environment, I got the response successfully like [this](https://i.imgur.com/n8UlYJ5.png). Note that, there will be delay of 15-20 minutes after assigning Admin role/permissions to take effect.

Comment: @Sridevi what kind of permission (delegated API permission) does your SP has? Is it Dataset.Read.All?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I got **`403 Forbidden`** error when I tried to query the data set with token generated with **invalid** scope:

```
GET https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/{group_id}/datasets
```

**Response:**

[image]

> To **resolve** the error, make sure to generate access token by passing **scope** value as `https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api/.default`

I created one AAD security group and added **`PowerBI App`** service principal to it like this:

[image]

Now, I allowed this group to call Power BI API by adding it under below option in Admin portal:

[image]

Make sure to grant access to either the **service principal** or **security group** for your Power Bi workspace:

[image]

> Note that, you need to wait for **`15-20`** minutes after granting
> access to the service principal as there will be delay.

Now, I generated access token using **client credentials** flow via Postman with below parameters:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token
grant_type:client_credentials
client_id: appId 
client_secret: secret 
scope: https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api/.default
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I used this token to query dataset, I got **response** successfully like this:

```
GET https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/{group_id}/datasets
```

**Response:**

[image]

**Reference:**
[Embed Power BI content with service principal and an application secret - Power BI | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-service-principal#method)